# Ruby making an array with numbers and ranges

Tags: ruby, arrays, range

I want to make an array with numbers and ranges. Like this:

```
range = [12, (1..11)]
```

Which should then look like:

```
[12, 1, 2, 3...11]
```

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 7):

Here's a shorter version:

```
[12, *(1..11)] # => [12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

It's called the splat operator (in case you didn't know).

Comment: That is insanely awesome.

Answer (score 4):

So one* way to do this is to say this:

```
range = [12, (1..11).to_a].flatten
```

### Explanation

The problem here is that `(1..11)` isn't an array. It's a range, but I thought that it was an array. So we first have to convert it into an array:

```
(1..11).to_a
```

Now, the problem is that we have a multidimensional array. Right?

```
[12, (1..11).to_a] # => [12, [1, 2, 3...11]]
```

To convert this into a single array we have to `flatten` it:

```
[12, (1..11).to_a].flatten # => [12, 1, 2, 3...11]
```

Voila!

I'd love to see other people's answers.

*This is one reason why I love Ruby so much.

Answer (score 2):

```
[12, (1..11)].flat_map{|i| i.is_a?(Range) ? i.to_a : i}
# => [12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```